# Car Salesman Calculator

Tags: python-3.x, input, output

I am trying to write a program that calculates a dealer profit for pre owned (get 25% of sales profit) and new car sales (get 35% of sales profit). It should compute the commission for both, then add together to get total commission.  My program is running with the output needed, but when it gets to the total commission, I am getting the error listed below:

```
Enter pre-owned sales profit: 3600
Enter new sales profit: 18000
Pre_owned_sales * 0.25/100: $900
Commission new sales * 0.35/100: $6300
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Darlene/Desktop/CAR_SALES_PROFIT04232016.py", line 15, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Darlene/Desktop/CAR_SALES_PROFIT04232016.py", line 6, in main
    total = float(input('Total Commission:$', commission_preowned_sales,'+',commission_new_sales))
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 4
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong in the program below?:

```
def main():
    pre_owned_vehicles = float(input("Enter pre-owned sales profit: "))
    new_vehicles = float(input("Enter new sales profit: "))
    commission_preowned_sales = float(input("Pre_owned_sales *0.25/100: $"))
    commission_new_sales = float(input("Commission new sales *0.35/100: $"))
    total = float(input('Total Commission:$', commission_preowned_sales,'+',commission_new_sales))
    print('Pre-owned_sales_profit is $',format(pre-owned_sales_profit,'.2f'))
    print('New_sales_profit_is $',format(new_sales,'.2f'))
    print('Pre-owned_commission_is $',format(Pre-owned_commission,'.2f'))
    print('New_sales_commission_is $',format(new_sales_commission,'.2f'))
    print(profit + commission,'$',format(total_pay,'.2f'),sep='')



main()
```

Comment: You can do your string formatting/substitutions like this `total = float(input('Total Commission:${} + {}'.format(commission_preowned_sales,commission_new_sales)))`

Answer (score 0):

If `commission_preowned_sales` and `commission_new_sales` are the only variables needed for `total`, `total` requires no additional input from the user, in which case `input` is being used unnecessarily. The error arises because the `input` function only takes one argument (a `string` to print in the console requesting input). Consider updating to `total = commission_preowned_sales + commission_new_sales`. `float` is technically optional here, since those variables were already converted to float.